# Ansible task to create a package with nginx 1.24.0 package with Modsecurty and listens on 443 inspects traffic with owasp rules

Tags: nginx, owasp, mod-security, web-application-firewall

Here is my ansible code

- name: Create Nginx WAF Package for Red Hat 8.7
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  become: true

  tasks:

  - name: Install required system packages for compilation
    yum:
    name:
    - gcc
    - make
    - openssl-devel
    - pcre-devel
    - zlib-devel
    - libxml2-devel
    - libxslt-devel
    - libcurl-devel
    - yajl-devel
    - lmdb-devel
    - ssdeep-devel
    state: latest
  - name: Install Epel repository
    yum:
    name: epel-release
    state: latest
  - name: Install additional packages
    yum:
    name:
    - git
    - automake
    - autoconf
    - libtool
    state: latest
  - name: Download ModSecurity source code
    get_url:
    url: "https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/archive/v3.0.4.tar.gz"
    dest: "/tmp/modsecurity.tar.gz"
  - name: Extract ModSecurity source code
    unarchive:
    src: "/tmp/modsecurity.tar.gz"
    dest: "/tmp"
    remote_src: true
  - name: Compile and install ModSecurity
    shell: |
    cd /tmp/ModSecurity-3.0.4
    git submodule init
    git submodule update
    ./build.sh
    ./configure
    make
    make install
    args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  - name: Download Nginx source code
    get_url:
    url: "http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.21.0.tar.gz"
    dest: "/tmp/nginx-1.21.0.tar.gz"
  - name: Extract Nginx source code
    unarchive:
    src: "/tmp/nginx-1.21.0.tar.gz"
    dest: "/tmp"
    remote_src: true
  - name: Download ModSecurity Nginx Connector
    get_url:
    url: "https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity-nginx/archive/v1.0.2.tar.gz"
    dest: "/tmp/modsecurity-nginx.tar.gz"
  - name: Extract ModSecurity Nginx Connector
    unarchive:
    src: "/tmp/modsecurity-nginx.tar.gz"
    dest: "/tmp"
    remote_src: true
  - name: Compile Nginx with ModSecurity
    shell: |
    cd /tmp/nginx-1.21.0
    ./configure 
    --with-compat 
    --add-dynamic-module=/tmp/ModSecurity-nginx-1.0.2
    make modules
    args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  - name: Create Nginx WAF package
    shell: tar -czvf /tmp/nginx_waf.tar.gz -C /tmp/nginx-1.21.0/objs/ ngx_http_modsecurity_module.so

It to create a package but failing with error

Configure: error: no ModSecurity/config was found

Comment: Hmmm... this is very strange. There is no ModSecurity/config file et all, but there is a 'config' file under ModSecurity-nginx directory. What if you try to run the packages manually?